# Request.Form() not working

Tags: ajax, json, asp-classic

I have a file intended to send data to server via Ajax, I've tried some libraries but I cant get them to work so I´m trying the simple Request.Form() method in the ASP server file, not working either.

the Ajax post:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/serv/sync.asp", true);
DataToSend = "id=1";                
xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", function () {
    if(xmlhttp.status === 200){
        //event handler
    };
}, false); 
xmlhttp.send(DataToSend);
```

the ASP file:

```
<%@language=vbscript%>
<%
    value = Request.Form("id")
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
    response.write (value) 
%>
```

Wat's the problem with this? I've checked the Post in console and its working, but I can't catch the values on the server side.

The original idea was to send a Json string, parse it in the server and do the dataBase inserts, but couldn't get it to work, does anyone have a working snippet or a link to a working Json parsing method in Classic ASP?
Thanks.

Note: I've tried changing the server file to a different  folder due to threading issues, and changing the URL to "http://127.0.0.1/serv/sync.asp".

Comment: I think that this can help you with JSON encoded data: http://github.com/rcdmk/aspjson

Comment: Because of the Same Origin Police you will have to run this on the same domain. If you are using "localhost", use "localhost" for the request aswell. If you are usnig the IP, so use the IP. IP and domain are considered as 2 different domains, even when it's reffering to the same address.

Comment: This sounds good, anyway do you know how to catch the Json string from the Post? Something like `jsonString = Request.Form("dataToSend")` have you used it?

Comment: "1" is not valid XML. Change the content type to plain text and you'll see the response.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this with success:

JS:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    httprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httprequest.texto = busca.id;
} else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
    httprequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    httprequest.texto = busca.id;
} else {
    alert("Seu navegador não suporta Ajax.");
    return false;
}

if (httprequest.readyState == 4 || httprequest.readyState == 0) {
    var busca = escape("texto texto texto");

    httprequest.open("POST", "../busca_ajax.asp", true);
    httprequest.onreadystatechange = retornaValores; 
    httprequest.send("busca=" + busca + "&teste=2");
}

function retornaValores() {
    if (httprequest.readyState == 4) {
        alert(httprequest.responseText);        
    }
}
```

ASP:

```
 dim busca
 busca = trim(request("busca"))

 response.write busca
```

**Edit:**

if you can, I recommend you to use jQuery. It eases the process a lot:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "lista.asp",
    data: { 'ajax': 's', 'dados': '{"id": 123, "nome":"teste"}'},
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(dados) {
        alert(dados);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("ERRO!");
    }
});
```

ASP:

```
dim ajax, id
ajax = request.form("ajax")
dados = request.form("dados") ' this is a JSON string

response.write dados
```

Comment: It's not working for me... I've copied everything, got the JQuery library, the Post is sent but I'm not catching anything on the other side. Tried `dados = request.form("dados").count`, returns "0"...

Comment: Ok, It was missing the `type: 'POST',` parameter, sending a default "GET" request. Catching it now. Thanks!

Comment: Sem problemas. Bom Natal pra você também.